# Openlayers Google Maps layers remain blank in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-maps, openlayers

I've created a map page using OpenLayers.  The user can select a specific thematic overlay (noise levels) by period, noise source and year.

I wanted to allow the user to choose a base (or background) layer: one of two (public) OpenStreetMap layers, the Google base layers, or one of Yahoo! Maps’ layers.
I originally wanted to provide Bing maps (Virtual Earth) as well, but since those use a different projection, I can’t use them in combination with my overlays (custom-served tiles).

It all works fine in almost all browsers: Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera (if you don’t click too much).  But when using Internet Explorer (versions 7 and 8), selecting one of the Google Maps layers results in a blank background.
I’ve tested with Fiddler, and the tiles aren’t even retrieved.

I’m running into a wall here.

Has anybody run into this problem before (and preferably: solved it)?  Or does someone have an idea what could be going wrong?

**Edit:** The site is located at http://software.dgmr.nl/geluidskaart/.

Comment: Maybe this is a little bit out of topic but you have the same problem with the "Map Data" popup when Google Maps are selected. As you probably can see in ol examples it is absent because new version of Google layer is used there. I was forced to use ol 2.10 so I just added the new version of layer implementation in script tag and used it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had an issue before with Google base layers when using an overview window, and a mix of Yahoo and Google layers.

Try removing the Yahoo layers to see if this is the issue (or the overview map).

I believe there could be a clash of variable names with this combination of JavaScript libraries.

There is an error reported in IE in the ymapapi file:

*this.MP is null or not an object*

**Edit**: There is a problem with your CSS. The Google layer / images are loading without problems, but you have a  "background: url(http://js.mapbox.com/theme/dark/blank.gif);" attribute on your Google layer. I removed this and the Google maps were displayed without problems.

This appears in your OpenLayers.Layer.Google_95_EventPane DIV.

Comment: Hm... Yes, I’ve seen this exact error pop up as well, but that occurs on all browsers, seemingly without affecting normal use.  I’d already tried removing the Yahoo! maps, and that doesn’t seem to have any effect.  I’ll try removing the overview map, though.  Thanks for the tip; I’ll report whether it works!

Comment: Let me know how you get on. I ditched the overview map in the end. Possibly related: http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/ticket/2057

Comment: Alas, no joy.  I’ve removed all base layers but the OSM mapnik and OSMarender ones (plus the Google ones), and I also removed the overview map, all to no avail.  The Google layers refuse to load.  :-(

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  You’re right, and I was still referencing the online version of the theme.  I’ve fixed both problems at once by using a local version of the theme files, and I’ve made the blank.gif file transparent.  The Google layers immediately become apparent.  It would appear to be an IE-specific ‘fix’ of OpenLayers, since the Google_95_EventPane div doesn’t have this background-image property in the other browsers...

Answer (score 4):

[See #7 of this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1159250#comment-4483828), it seems to fix the problem. 
Not sure, if it is directly related to your issue though.

Try removing `"blank.gif"` from the dark theme image folder. 
It also made it work in IE.